# Strange equality involving a geometric series and gamma and zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, gamma-function, zeta-functions

I saw someone do this (in a youtube video):

$$\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{n}^\text{s}}=\Gamma\left(\text{s}\right)\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}=\Gamma\left(\text{s}\right)\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\left\{\int_0^\infty\text{u}^{\text{s}-1}e^{-\text{n}\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\right\}=$$
$$\int_0^\infty\text{u}^{\text{s}-1}\left\{\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty e^{-\text{n}\text{u}}\right\}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\int_0^\infty\text{u}^{\text{s}-1}\cdot\frac{1}{e^\text{u}-1}\space\text{d}\text{u}$$

But, I can follow all the steps he did but the last integral does not converge because the geometric series only hold when the real part of $\text{u}$ is bigger then $0$, but the lower bound of the integral equals $0$. So why are those two things equal?

Or can we assign a value to:

$$\lim_{u\to0}\text{u}^{\text{s}-1}\cdot\frac{1}{e^\text{u}-1}$$

Comment: The last integral exist as Lebesgue integral.

Comment: For small $u$, the integrand behaves as $u^{s-2}$.

Comment: @user2958701 The geometric series works like this: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{r-1}$$ When $|r|<1$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, but the sum does not exists at $u=0$?!

Comment: @user403351: I didn't say it exists. On the opposite, the behavior is $u^{-1}$. But the integral can very well converge thanks to the factor $u^{s-1}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see that the limit exists for $\Re(s)>1$. So then we can assign a value to $u=0$

Comment: @user403351: no, values with $1<\Re(s)\le2$ don' t work. But $\Re(s)<1$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Last statement could wrote like this
‎$$\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u-1}=\frac{e^{-u}u^{s-1}}{1-e^{-u}}=e^{-u}u^{s-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-ku}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-ku}u^{s-1}$$‎

Comment: Ok, but then does the integral not exists because of the lower bound $u=0$?!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we take integrals like this as follows:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u-1}\ du=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^1\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u-1}\ du+\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_1^b\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u-1}\ du$$

And when $s>1$, there is no problem as $a\to0$.

Comment: I would mention that $\int_0^\infty u^{s-1} \frac{e^{-u}-e^{-N u}}{1-e^{-u}}du =\Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$ and the result follows from $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_0^\infty u^{s-1} \frac{e^{-N u}}{1-e^{-u}}du = 0$